# Start in background and auto start disabled for an app with particular package name

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I have an app which uses a package Name. Whenever I install this app on Xiaomi phones the start in background and auto start are always disabled. We tried multiple things but somehow it does not enable on install. We have to keep asking users to do it manually. Surprisingly if I just change one letter of the package name currently being used the start in background is enabled. Can someone please help us understand why is it happening? Are device makers Loke Xiaomi having option to block any package names? Having this permission enabled is really crucial for us. All our other apps have this permission enabled. It’s just this app with this particular package name is where the issue is.

Comment: xiomi means xiaomi? and what's ur package name ? and changed package name?

Comment: Yes Xiaomi devices. Since its client thing i would not be able to give package name because of confidentiality agreement. Sorry about that. But in general wanted to know has anyone come across something similar? if yes what can we do?

Comment: Ok, each app installed will not able to auto start by default . but I can't quite understand why u change one letter auto start will work . the only perhaps I can guess is ur package name cause this .

Comment: Actually we did demo app to check the scenario. When we do it and run it it has auto start enabled.

Comment: it weired , actually I'm a developer in xiaomi china , seems like something different between cn version and global version . but its indeed depend on package name .